# How to click a dropdown arrow in extJS using Python and Selenium?

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, extjs

The full HTML code for the table is as follows:

```html
<table id="clearablecombo-1497" class="x-field clearableCombo x-form-item x-field-default x-anchor-form-item" cellpadding="0" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 287px;">
<tbody>
<tr id="clearablecombo-1497-inputRow">
<td id="clearablecombo-1497-labelCell" class="x-field-label-cell" width="105" valign="top" halign="right" style="">
<label id="clearablecombo-1497-labelEl" class="x-form-item-label x-form-item-label-right" style="width:100px;margin-right:5px;" for="clearablecombo-1497-inputEl">Document Status:</label>
</td>
<td id="clearablecombo-1497-bodyEl" class="x-form-item-body x-form-trigger-wrap-focus" colspan="2" role="presentation" style="width: 100%;">
<table id="clearablecombo-1497-triggerWrap" class="x-form-trigger-wrap" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="clearablecombo-1497-inputCell" class="x-form-trigger-input-cell" style="width: 100%;">
<div id="ext-gen1890" class="x-hide-display x-form-data-hidden" role="presentation"/>
<input id="clearablecombo-1497-inputEl" class="x-form-field x-form-text x-form-focus x-field-form-focus x-field-default-form-focus" type="text" style="width: 100%; text-transform: uppercase; -moz-user-select: text;" name="documentStatus" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false"/>
</td>
<td id="ext-gen1888" class="x-trigger-cell" valign="top" style="width:26px">
<div id="ext-gen1886" class="x-trigger-index-0 x-form-trigger x-form-arrow-trigger x-unselectable x-form-trigger-over x-form-arrow-trigger-over" role="button" style="-moz-user-select: none;"/>
</td>
<td id="ext-gen1889" class="x-trigger-cell" valign="top" style="width:26px">
<div id="ext-gen1887" class="x-trigger-index-1 x-form-trigger x-form-clear-trigger x-form-trigger-last x-unselectable" role="button" style="-moz-user-select: none;"/>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
<td id="clearablecombo-1497-errorEl" class="x-form-error-msg x-external-error-icon x-form-invalid-icon" width="0" style="display:none" data-errorqtip=""/>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The part of the HTML I'm attempting to manipulate is this part specifically:

```html
<div id="ext-gen1886" class="x-trigger-index-0 x-form-trigger x-form-arrow-trigger x-unselectable x-form-trigger-over x-form-arrow-trigger-over" role="button" style="-moz-user-select: none;"/>
```

The above part is the actual dropdown arrow which is also in the above large portion of the HTML. The drop down text I need to select is "Rejected". The HTML with the selection options are as follows:

```html
<div id="boundlist-1558" class="x-boundlist x-boundlist-floating x-layer x-boundlist-default" tabindex="-1" style="left: 136px; top: 346px; height: auto; z-index: 19001; width: 182px;">
<div id="boundlist-1558-listEl" class="x-boundlist-list-ct" style="overflow: auto; height: auto;">
<ul>
<li class="x-boundlist-item x-boundlist-item-over" role="option">All</li>
<li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">Waiting QA</li>
<li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">AutoTec Approved</li>
<li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">User Approved</li>
<li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">Rejected</li>
<li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">Deleted</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Anyone have any suggestions of the XPath I would use to do this? I tried just inputting the text like a textbox, however there are certain boxes such as the Country and State that have to be selected to enable each other.

Comment: where is your code? show what have you tried so far

Comment: `def set_dealerSearchDocumentsStatus(self, dealerSearchDocumentsStatus):
        webDocumentsStatus = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
            ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, NM.DP_DEALER_SEARCH_DOCUMENTS_STATUS)))
        webDocumentsStatus.send_keys(dealerSearchDocumentsStatus)
        sleep(0.25)
        webDocumentsStatus.send_keys(Keys.TAB)`

This works for inputting the text into the field as if it's a text box. However, I've had no luck selecting the dropdown arrow and selecting the value from there.

Comment: My problem of course is our application is written using sencha. The generation of the ID's is why I'm forced to use complex XPath statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think 'role' is the best attr in this case to find the elements:

```
--this one select your desired element
"//div[contains(id, 'ext-gen')][@role='button'][contains(@class, 'x-form-trigger-over')]"

--this one select your desired option
"//li[@role='option'][text()='Rejected']"
```

Comment: With the element XPath, will it not select all the dropdowns on the page? Don't they technically all match that XPath? Do I need to use indexing?

Comment: If the elements of xpath match with two or more dropdowns, you can use the index in the base tag. Example, if there are 3 tables like this, you can use the index in the table's tag and write your Xpath normally. Also, if you know and is displayed the name (in text) of the item that you want, you can navigate to him even if in a different tag. In XPath you can both compare a text inside selector as you can get the parent element.

Comment: I think we're on the same page, but just to be clear, could you give me an example. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: An example geting an element by name, geting the parent and selecting the button in the same selector.

https://jsfiddle.net/jweg20fw/

Comment: Even with the button is not inside the element you select initially, you can get te parent to navigate to button. to get the parent element in XPath, we use `/..`

Comment: Thank you for your time. You've been very helpful. You helped lead to my solution which was actually using an entirely different method, however your method did work with indexing, it was just too many and too much to maintain long term. This will help me very much in the future though with different scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand these are the target elements:

```
xpath = '//div[contains(id, "ext-gen")][@class="x-trigger-index-0 x-form-trigger x-form-arrow-trigger x-unselectable x-form-trigger-over x-form-arrow-trigger-over"]' 
drop_down = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
drop_down.click()
xpath = '//li[@class="x-boundlist-item"][contains(text(), "Rejected")]'
option = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
option.click()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. If there are multiple dropdowns that have the same attributes, which is the case, won't that XPath select them all? Do I need to use indexing? That may be the only way around it.

Comment: `XPath` might be more specific to match just required element. indexing is also an\ acceptible aproach